# InvalidParameter calling waveOutOpen MmException

Tags: c#, naudio, waveout

This code works on **32bit Windows XP** but on **64bit Windows 7** it raises an exception. (on any CPU configuration)

```
var format = NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat.CreateCustomFormat(
    WaveFormatEncoding.Pcm, 8000, 1, 16000, 1, 16)
BufferedWaveProvider myBufferedWaveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(format);
myWaveOut.Init(myBufferedWaveProvider);
```

Any help?

Comment: what is the exception message

Comment: InvalidParameter calling waveOutOpen MmException

Comment: can you try WaveFormatExtensible instead of WaveFormat.

Comment: I tried that, same exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've created an invalid WaveFormat. PCM 8kHz mono 16 bit (which is what you seem to be trying to make) has a block align of 2. There's an easier way to make this WaveFormat in NAudio:

```
new WaveFormat(8000, 1);
```